# Tweepy tracking terms and following users

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth, tweepy

I'm trying to build an app to track some terms from specifics users using the streaming twitter API.

I made a working python script using tweepy for the streaming api based on this [tutorial](http://andrewbrobinson.com/2011/07/15/using-tweepy-to-access-the-twitter-stream/). But, it's only working if I track tweets by terms or by user ids, but now by both. When I try to search using both of them, the api returns me tweets from any user. My code is here:

```
#Acessando a API do twitter com as chaves
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token_key, access_token_secret)

#Chamando o Listener com o tweepy
api = tweepy.API(auth)

#Chama o stream e passa o que buscar no twitter.
sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())
list_users = ['11111','22222']   #Some ids
list_terms = ['term1','term2']   #Some terms
sapi.filter(follow=list_users, track=list_terms)
```

These two variables(`list_users`, `list_terms`) are lists of user ids and list of terms respectively.

How can I filter tweets stream by users AND by terms? Is there any way to do it with the tweepy filter? Or should I do a verification after retrieving the tweet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter streaming API evaluates different conditions with `OR` logic, that is returns union of tweets with terms and from users. So you have to implement custom `on_data` function in order to filter with `AND`.

Note that you're limited to condition on up to [5000 users and 400 terms](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/4120), and as rate limit may be an issue, so you'd supply api with a condition that yields lower tweet stream, and filter incoming data with all the rest conditions in post processing.

> You can track up to 5,000 users and 400 keywords -- the rate limiting indeed takes effect at 1% of the Firehose, so if at any moment the tweet volume from the union of your keywords and users rises above 1% of all tweets happening in "real time" on the Firehose, you'll get up to 1% of the tweets along with a rate limit notice informing you of how many tweets you missed.