# How do I filter tweets using location AND keyword?

Tags: python, tweepy

I'm a new Python user and have been experimenting with tweepy.  I understand the twitter API does not allow for filtering on both location and keywords.  To get around this, I've adapted the code from here: [How to add a location filter to tweepy module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22889122/how-to-add-a-location-filter-to-tweepy-module?rq=1).  While it works fine when there are only a few keywords, it ceases to print out statuses when I increase the number of keywords.  I think it's probably because iterating over the keyword list is not the best way to do it.  Does anyone have any suggestions on how to resolve this?

```
import sys
import tweepy
import json

consumer_key=" "
consumer_secret=" "
access_key = " "
access_secret = " "

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_key, access_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
### keywords for the public stream
keyword = "iPhone", "Samsung", "HTC", "Sony", "Blackberry"
### initialize blank list to contain tweets
tweets = []
### file name that you want to open is the second argument
f = open('today.txt', 'a')

class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    global tweets
    def on_status(self, status):
        ### info that you want to capture
        info = status.id, status.text, status.created_at, status.place, status.user, status.in_reply_to_screen_name, status.in_reply_to_status_id 
        for word in keyword:
            if word in status.text.lower():
                print status.text
                # this is for writing the tweets into the txt file
                f.write(str(info))
                try:
                    tweets.append(info)
                except:
                    pass


    def on_error(self, status_code):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Encountered error with status code:', status_code
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        print >> sys.stderr, 'Timeout...'
        return True # Don't kill the stream

### filter for location
# locations should be a pair of longtitude and latitude pairs, with the southwest corner
# of the bounding box coming first
sapi = tweepy.streaming.Stream(auth, CustomStreamListener())    
sapi.filter(locations=[103.60998,1.25752,104.03295,1.44973])
```

Comment: u can use multiple threads tosearch keyword

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Regular expressions to search the tweet. as follows

```
    import re
    keyword = ["iPhone", "Samsung", "HTC", "Sony", "Blackberry"]
    patterns = [r'\b%s\b' % re.escape(s.strip()) for s in keyword.lower()]
    there = re.compile('|'.join(patterns))
    stream=["i have a iPhone","i dont like Samsung","HTC design are awesome","Sony camera is good","Blackberry lost market","Nokia soldout to windows"]
    for i in stream:
        if there.search(i):
            print("Tweet Found  %r" % (i))
```

Comment: I tried as you suggested but do not seem to get any results.  Would you know why?

Comment: `def on_status(self, status):
        for tweet in status.text.lower():
            if there.search(tweet):
                print tweet`

Comment: can u give sample data of tweet

Comment: this is how a single status.text.lower() looks like:   `I'm at Transitlink Pte Ltd http://t.co/0JhGxzsiEu`

Comment: @eugeneyan just give if there.search(status.text.lower()):

Comment: @eugeneyan actually status text is a line. directly put it in there.search(status.text.lower())

Comment: @eugeneyan and also put . lower to keywords. see i have edited it. since we are lower in the status. v need to lower the keywords

Comment: perfect! It works fine.  I have since amended my code to store tweets in json; would you be able to suggest how I should implement it in here?  `class CustomStreamListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
    def __init__(self, api):
        self.api = api
        super(tweepy.StreamListener, self).__init__()

        self.file = tweets

    def on_data(self, tweet):
        self.file.append(json.loads(tweet))
        print tweet
        file.write(str(tweet))`