# Filtering Twitter data using Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, twitter-oauth, tweepy

I've used Marco Bonzanini's tutorial on mining Twitter data : https://marcobonzanini.com/2015/03/02/mining-twitter-data-with-python-part-1/

```
class MyListener(StreamListener):

    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            with open('python.json', 'a') as f:
                f.write(data)
                return True
        except BaseException as e:
            print(&quot;Error on_data: %s&quot; % str(e))
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True
```

and used the "follow" parameter of the filter method to retrieve the tweets produced by this specific ID :

```
twitter_stream = Stream(auth, MyListener())
twitter_stream.filter(follow=["63728193"#random Twitter ID])
```

However, it does not seem to fulfill the mission since it not only returns the tweets & retweets created by the ID, but also every tweet wherein the ID is mentioned (i.e. retweets). That is not what I want.

I'm sure there must be a way to do it since there is a "screen_name" field in the json file given by Twitter. That screen_name field gives the name of the creator of the Tweet. I just have to find how to filter the data on this screen_neame field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This behaviour is by design. To quote the [Twitter streaming API docs](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/overview/request-parameters):

> For each user specified, the stream will contain:
>
> - Tweets created by the user.
> - Tweets which are retweeted by the user.
> - Replies to any Tweet created by the user.
> - Retweets of any Tweet created by the user.
> - Manual replies, created without pressing a reply button (e.g. “@twitterapi I agree”).

The best way for you to process it for your purposes is to check who created the tweet as it is received, which I believe can be done as follows:

```
class MyListener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            if data._json['user']['id'] == "63728193":
                with open('python.json', 'a') as f:
                    f.write(data)
        except BaseException as e:
            print(&quot;Error on_data: %s&quot; % str(e))
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True
```

Comment: Not sure what your comment is getting at here?

Comment: Your code is almost ok. However `data` is not a JSON object but a str object. You have to convert `data` from str to dict before doing a request on it : 

`class MyListener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        try:
            data = json.loads(data)
            if data['user']["screen_name"] == "lemondefr":
                    print(data)
        except BaseException as e:
            print(str(e))
        return True

    def on_error(self, status):
        print(status)
        return True`

Comment: @NahidO. a `Status` object in Tweepy has a `._json` property, which should let you access the various properties of the tweet as described in my answer. I'd be interested to know if using `data._json['user']['screen_name']` didn't work for you

Comment: I don't know why it didn't work. Maybe a `data`object doesn't work like a `Status` object ? I don't know that much about tweepy.

If you look at this other tweepy post : 

(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23531608/how-do-i-save-streaming-tweets-in-json-via-tweepy)

the user also converted his `data` object to a dict.

Comment: @NahidO. ah! I didn't realise the difference between `on_data(self, data)` and `on_data(self, status)`. The code I have provided actually would only work for `on_data(self, status)`, my mistake.